# Maximum projection on x-axis of a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, binary-tree

Given a binary tree in a coordinate plane with its root having coordinates (x,y) . We need to find the maximum projection on x-axis of this tree. That is , basically we need to find the MAXIMUM width of this tree. The tree can be skew as well.

Examples :

```
    1
   / \
  2   3
 /   / \
4   5   6
```

`Width = 5`

```
    1
   / \
  2   3
 /  
4
```

`Width = 4`

```
    1
   / 
  2  
 /   
4
```

`Width = 3`

My logic was to basically find the left most node and the right most node and subtract their x-coordinates. On going from root to left subtree `x` becomes `x-1` and y becomes `y+1` and on going to right subtree `x` becomes `x+1`. Upon finding these 2 coordinates xLeft and xRight , we can find the maximum width. But I was having trouble coding it.

Can anyone tell how to go about it ? It is not a homework question , but it was a programming puzzle I read somewhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tree visualization algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368386/tree-visualization-algorithm)

Comment: @mbeckish- I don't think this question is at all a duplicate.  The linked question is about how to lay out the nodes in a tree.  This one is a question about discovering a structural property of a tree.

Comment: @templatetypedef - Both questions are about determining the width of a specific graphical representation of the tree, correct?  If that is not what this question is about, then what is your definition of "maximum width"?

Comment: I think @kasavbere got it right before the additional edits. But you need to tell us, how are you calculating `width=5`? are you saying the x-coordinate of 4 is `0` and that of 6 is `5`? Because in reality that width should be 4 since `2 - -2 = 4`. More details please.

Answer (score 1):

This is a level-order traversal problem. As you traverse the tree in level order, track the width of the largest level. When you are done, the leftmost node and the rightmost node at that level will give you the final projection you are looking for.

EDIT:

mbeckish: The above solution assumes the question was about the largest cross-section. But if that's not the case, level order still works. Except the code must track both `minX` and `maxX` during traversal. `minX` would track the leftmost node and `maxX` would track the rightmost node. Then the answer would be `maxX-minX+1`.

[This site](http://www.geekviewpoint.com/java/bst/levelorder) has a number of well-documented bst traversal code you can modify.

Comment: Does your solution give Width = 5 or Width = 3 for the Op's first example?

Comment: @mbeckish good catch. I edit. Indeed it is level-order. Except my original response was for largest cross-section.

Comment: I think you got it right before your edits. The problem with the OP is that it's lacking details of what the coordinates actually are. I'll ask for details.

Comment: @mbeckish the OP is indeed confusing a bit, since it's lacking details. How do you understand it?

Comment: @kasavbere I understand this as placing the nodes into discrete columns and rows (like the pixels of a bitmap or text rows and columns), and arranging the nodes so that the tree is arranged in a nice pyramid-like structure (with each node centered over its subtree).  The problem then is to determine the number of columns necessary to hold the entire tree.

Comment: I might be misinterpreting the question, but are you sure that this works?  I think that this won't correctly account for the first case described, since it's the position of the nodes rather than the number that matters.

Comment: @templatetypedef I think I might have misunderstood the question at first, but if mbeckish's assessment is correct, my latest edit is correct. The code must track minX and maxX seen so far during traversal. Based on mbeckish's explanation, your code seems also to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by doing a standard tree traversal algorithm while maintaining the x coordinate of the current node.  Whenever you go left, you decrement x, and whenever you go right, you decrement x.  This is shown here:

```
void ExtremalNodes(Node* curr, int x, int& maxX, int& minX) {
    if (curr == nullptr) return;
    maxX = std::max(x, maxX);
    minX = std::min(x, minY);
    ExtremalNodes(curr->left, x - 1, maxX, minX);
    ExtremalNodes(curr->right, x + 1, maxX, minX);
}
int TreeProjection(Node* root) {
    if (root == nullptr) return 0;

    int maxX = 0;
    int minX = 0;
    ExtremalNodes(root, 0, maxX, minX);
    return maxX - minX + 1;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How do you know the x coordinate of each node?  From your recursive calls to ExtremalNodes, it looks like you are assuming that the left child is always one unit to the left of its parent, and the right child is always one unit to the right of the parent.  That is not the case in general.  For example, with a complete binary tree, the left and right children of the root will be spread fairly widely apart to make room for their wide subtrees.

Comment: @mbeckish- The OP explicitly mentioned that going to a left or right child changes the x by +/-1, which is where this answer comes from.  I agree that this won't work in practice, but I assumed this was more of a theoretical question.